# Como aplicar Opacity no IE8

Tags: css

Tenho uma linha que aplica um opacity em um Background, com esse CSS:

```
.teste{background-color: rgba(27,18,9,0.9);}
```

Todos sabemos que o IE8 não aceita opacidade, existe algum hack para isso?

Comment: Opacidade ou RGBA? Opacity pega TODO o elemento e deixa ele mais ou menos transparente. RGBA, no caso, deixaria o fundo opaco mas não influenciaria em outro elementos dentro desse elemento. RGBA não funciona no IE8- : (

Answer (score 2):

Ta ai

```
.transparent_class {


-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)"; // first!
filter: alpha(opacity=50);                  // second!


  /* Netscape */
  -moz-opacity: 0.5;

  /* Safari 1.x */
  -khtml-opacity: 0.5;

  /* Good browsers */
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Poderia tentar tambem algo assim:

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#4cFF0000,endColorstr=#4cFF0000);
```

Comment: Tentei cara, mas não rolou, olha aí http://jsfiddle.net/1cc4zra2/

Comment: Você esta emulando ou utilizando a versão correta ?

Comment: Pelos testes que fiz aqui já que desenvolvemos com o IE8 deu certo somente com o filter, mas emulando não funciona, só com o browser mesmo

Comment: Estou utilizando o IE8 diretamente de uma máquina virtual, utilizando Virtual Box.

Comment: dei uma editada veja se ajuda

Comment: Mudei cara, e ainda não funfa http://jsfiddle.net/1cc4zra2/1/
estou pensando em usar um .png transparente, mas gostaria de descobrir na unha qual o problema.

Comment: atualizei o código talvez te ajude

Comment: Você atualizou no JSFiddle?

Comment: não somente a resposta

Comment: Não rolou amigo, acho que o ideal é eu fazer um png transparente mesmo.

Comment: Acho que será mais prático, desculpe não ter conseguido ajudar

Comment: Que isso cara, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta com este código.

```
.minha-classe {
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";   
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    -moz-opacity:0.5;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Abraços!